# Optimal control: coarse control and fine dynamics

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

Consider the time evolution of a probability distribution $P(\alpha_{t})$ as follows.

\begin{equation}
P(\alpha_{t}) = F[P(\alpha_{t-1}), U_t(y_{t-1})],
\end{equation} where $y_{t-1} = \mathcal{P}\alpha_{t-1}$, with $\mathcal{P}$ being some projection matrix, and $U$ being a control variable.

I wish to find a set of functions $\{U_t(y_{t-1})\}_{t=1}^{t=T}$, such that $\langle f(\alpha_T)\rangle_{P(\alpha_T)} \to \max$, for some known function $f$.

My questions:

1. Is such a scenario already explored? If so, can you share with me the literature?
2. If it is trivial, can you share with me the Bellman equation that needs to be solved?

Additional info.:

1. The initial conditions of $\alpha$ (and hence $y$) are known.
2. $\alpha$'s belong to a countable and bounded space.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150528/discussion-on-question-by-prakhar-godara-optimal-control-coarse-control-and-fin); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.